# Issue Read/Write array of structure in binary file in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, binaryfiles, read-write

I want to write my array structure in to a binary file.

**My structure**

```
typedef struct student{
     char name[15];
     vector<int> grade;
}arr_stu;
```

I can write and read back my data if I write and read in the same program; but if I create another program for read data only and put the binary file, it does not work because the vector grade is null.

```
size = 0;
unable to read from memory
```

**Program to write array structure to file**

```
int main()
{
arr_stu stu[100];

for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    strcpy(stu[i].name, randomName());
    for (size_t j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        stu[i].grade.push_back(randomGrade());
    }
}   

ofstream outbal("class", ios::out | ios::binary);
if (!outbal) {
    cout << "Cannot open file.\n";
    return 1;
}

outbal.write((char *)&stu, sizeof(stu));
outbal.close();
}
```

**Program to read array structure to file**

```
int main(){

    feature_struc stu[100];

    ifstream inbal("class", ios::in | ios::binary);
if (!inbal) {
    cout << "Cannot open file.\n";
    return 1;
}

inbal.read((char *)&stu, sizeof(stu));

for (size_t idx = 0; idx < 100; idx++)
{
    cout << "Name :  " << stu[idx].name << endl;   
    for (size_t index = 0; index < 10; index++)
    {
        cout << endl << "test: " << stu[idx].grade[index] << endl;
    }
}
inbal.close();
return 0;
}
```

For me it seems like the use of vector pose the problem,
The reason that if we combine the two in one program it work well I think because vector is saved in the memory so it can still accessible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You do not need the `typedef struct...`, and you should also be using more `std::vector` as well as `std::string` instead of arrays and C strings.

Comment: It's mandatory you use a binary file for this?  Can't you use something like `XML`, `YAML`, `JSON` or even `sqlite` if you want to keep things in binary style?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot serialize a vector like that. The `write` and `read` functions access the memory at the given address directly. Since `vector` is a complex class type only parts of its data content are stored sequentially at its base address. Other parts (heap allocated memory etc) are located elsewhere. The simplest solution would be to write the length of the vector to the file followed by each of the values. You have to loop over the vector elements to accomplish that.

Comment: are there any solution not to loop over all the vector elements in case we have large contents?

Comment: The vector implementation in C++11 provides a `data` member function returning a pointer to the allocated memory directly which could be used for serializing the contents. Previous standards do not provide this function so you can't avoid iterating over the contents.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at the [boost::serialization library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) which implements generic patterns for serializing objects

Comment: @sayvortana If you have a vector `v` of POD members (type `T` e.g. `T==int`) you can directly access the full data by `const T* p=&v[0]` in pre-C++11. Furthermore, you know the size by `sizeof(T)*v.size()`. Therefore, writing without looping is possible. More complex data types `T` are problematic.

Comment: @Tobias I'm not sure if pre-C++11 standards actually guarantee that the vector elements are stored contiguously in memory. It should also be noted that this won't work for `vector<bool>` as there is a specialization which uses only one bit per element.

Comment: Citation from Section [vector.overview] of the C++ spec.: The elements of a
vector are stored contiguously, meaning that if v is a vector<T, Allocator> where T is some type other
than bool, then it obeys the identity &v[n] == &v[0] + n for all 0 <= n < v.size().
BTW, writing the whole data block into a vector (with sufficient space) is analogously possible.

Comment: @jasal His vector contains `int`, and even a `ostream::write` of an `int` will result in something that he may not be able to read later.

Answer (score 1):

`outbal.write((char *)&stu, sizeof(stu));`

The `sizeof` is a compile-time constant.  In other words, it never changes.  If the vector contained 1, 10, 1000, or 1,000,000 items, you're writing the same number of bytes to the file.  So this way of writing to the file is totally wrong.

The struct that you're writing is `non-POD` due to the `vector` being a non-POD type.  This means you can't just treat it as a set of bytes that you can copy from or to.   If you want further proof, open the file you created in any editor.  Can you see the data from the vector in that file?  What you will see is more than likely, gibberish.

To write the data to the file, you have to properly serialize the data, meaning you have to write the *data* to a file, not the `struct` itself.  You write the data in a way so that when you read the data back, you can recreate the struct.  Ultimately, this means you have to

1. Write the name to the file, and possibly the number of bytes the name consists of.
2. Write the number of items in the vector
3. Write each vector item to the file.

If not this, then some way where you can distinctly figure out the name and the vector's data from the file so that your code to read the data parses the file correctly and recreates the struct.

Comment: You can't write PODs this way, either, and expect to be able to reread them.

Answer (score 0):

What is the format of the binary file?  Basically, you have to
define the format, and then convert each element to and from
that format.  You can never just dump the bits of an internal
representation to disk and expect to be able to read it back.
(The fact that you need a `reinterpret_cast` to call
`ostream::write` on your object should tell you something.)